# Laravel Spatie Model Status

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso de uma ajuda para implementar um status do pedido.
Estou em um projeto que na sessão de pedidos, eu detalho um pedido especifico. Dentro dele vai ter um `select`para selecionar o `STATUS`do pedido, se foi `pago`, `entregue`, `cancelado` e etc.

Mas não sei qual a melhor forma de implementar isso, me deram um pacote que é esse: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-model-status#assign-statuses-to-eloquent-models

Onde tem situação do pedido é para vir o `STATUS` do pedido e também onde posso muda-lo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo, jovem. É o seguinte: porque não tenta implementar isso "na mão"?  Você pode fazer isso facilmente criando uma tabela `status_pedido` e relacionando ela com um campo `status_pedido_id`. Eu particularmente acho um desperdício usar uma lib só pra isso.

Comment: Eu tbm, mas o gerente do projeto que usar isso para fazer o status. Por mim tinha feito desse jeito que você falou, mas...

Comment: Gerente de projeto as vezes mais atrapalha do que ajuda.

Comment: Você quer instruções para executar a instalação? No próprio  projeto do GITHUB está ensinando isso. Tente traduzir a página e executar os passos com calma.

Comment: Isso já está instalado no projeto, seguir os passos mas nada sai.
Nunca usei esse pacote e particularmente acho bem inutil, mas o problema ainda é que tem 12 status, e é dividido em perfils, tipo ACL, que cada perfil so pode alterar certos status.